# Non-dense sets and their boundaries

Tags: general-topology

**Question**

Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be such that for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$,  $E_i$ is closed with non-empty interior, that is, $\text{Int}(E_i)\neq\emptyset$. Set
\begin{equation}
E=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}E_i.
\end{equation}If $E$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then is
\begin{equation}
\partial E\subset\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\partial E_i?
\end{equation}

**Motivation/my work**

I understand that if we allow $\text{Int}(E_i)=\emptyset$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, then the rationals $\mathbb{Q}^2$ form a dense set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and \begin{equation}
\partial\mathbb{Q}^2\subsetneq\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}^2}\partial \{q\}.
\end{equation}Thus, requiring that the interiors be non-empty excludes this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}E_n$ where $E_n$ is the closed disk with center $(\frac1n,0)$ and radius $\frac1{2n},$ then $(0,0)\in\partial E$ but $(0,0)\notin\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\partial E_n.$