# Is this set countable?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My motivation for this question comes from this [earlier question and its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568769/non-dense-sets-and-their-boundaries/). 
Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be such that for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$,  $E_i$ is closed with non-empty interior, that is, $\text{Int}(E_i)\neq\emptyset$. Set
\begin{equation}
E=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}E_i.
\end{equation}If $E$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathcal{L}^2(\partial E)\neq 0$, then is $\partial E\setminus\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\partial E_i$ countable? Here, $\mathcal{L}^2$ denotes the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Great answers below, but I am interested in the case that $\mathcal{L}^2(\partial E)\neq 0$. I've edited the question to reflect this. Apologies for not having that detail in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

False. Here is a counterexample. Let $E_i$ be a sequence of closed disks with center at the origin, where $E_i$ has radius $2-1/i$.

Then the $E_i$ is an increasing sequence of closed disks approaching the disk with radius 2 at the origin, and hence $E$ is the *open* disk with radius 2 at the origin.

So $\partial E$ is the circle with radius 2 at the origin, and is trivially disjoint from $\partial E_i$, which is the circle of radius $2-1/i$ centered at the origin. So $\partial E\backslash \bigcup \partial E_i=\partial E$ is uncountable.

Comment: Would it be true if, furthermore, $\mathcal{L}^2(\partial E)\neq 0$? Here, $\mathcal{L}^2$ denotes the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Well no, because in this example already, $\mathcal L^2(\partial E)=0$ already because a circle is one-dimensional in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_i=[\frac1i,2]\times[0,1].$ Then
$$\partial\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}\partial E_i=\{0\}\times[0,1].$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ E_n\ :=\ [0;\frac {n-1}n]^2\ $ for $\ n=1\ 2\ \ldots.\ $ Then
$\ \delta E\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \delta E_n\ $ is not countable.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers by @bof and me are similar. I'll add another similar answer but I feel that it is more cute (a bit more elegant):

Let's consider disks:

$$ E_n\ :=\ \{ p\in\mathbb R^2: |p| \le 1-\frac 1{n+1} \} $$

Then $\ \delta E\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\delta E_n\ $ is not countable.